# FluidSelectOutput on different batches

Tags: java, anylogic

I'm new to Anylogic and I'm trying to make a model in which the source block is defined by arrival tables in the database.

In this table I indicate parameters for the agents generated in the source block, defining the agent's capacity (agent.capacity) and the type of fluid it transports (agent.tipo).

There are three types of fluid possible for the agent.tipo: Oil, Gasoline or Naphtha and the agent.capacity is equal to 80000 m3.

So far, the model is working and the agents are taking the values I determined for the parameters.

What I want to do is connect the source block to a FluidDropOff block so that agents can be converted to fluids in the model. My intention is to be able to divide the types of fluids into two tanks (as shown in the image).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/m041A.png

The FluidDropOff is defined as shown below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oddqz.png

In the "On empty" part of the Tank I defined that:

```
if (agent.produtoP.equals("GLP")) 
fluidSelectOutput.select(2);
```

But, apparently there's something wrong with the code. Anylogic returns the following error: agent cannot be resolved.

How could I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SOF. This place works best for you if you ask very focused, specific questions on 1 AnyLogic issue, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. If you want to know “how do I best do X in AnyLogic”, you should use the LinkedIn forum instead. Check this overview to the community to understand why: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community. Welcome again, happy to help